# How can I convert following string date-time into pandas datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, type-conversion

How can I convert the following string format of datetime into datetime object to be used in pandas Dataframe? I tried many examples, but it seems my format is different from the standard Pandas datetime object. I know this could be a repetition, but I tried solutions on the Stackexchange, but they don't work!

[image]

Comment: please do not post images of data, use text instead. also, please show what code you tried which did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code will convert it into appropriate format

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':['2013-11-1_00:00','2013-11-1_00:10','2013-11-1_00:20']})
df['datetime_changed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'].str.replace('_','T'))
df.head()
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.to_datetime` with `format`

```py
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M')
```